# Prepared Statement doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, prepared-statement

So we have a table with all our players and a table for every team. First I get the Id of players playing on this team and then I use said Id in order to get all the information abut this player.
A friend now told me that I could reduce the server response-time by using prepared statements. But it doesn't work! This is the error message "Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in "address" on line 63"

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT Vorname, Nachname, Bild FROM Spieler WHERE Id IN (?)");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $SpielerId);
$sql1 = "SELECT Id, SpielerId FROM 2Herren";
$list = $conn->query($sql1);
if ($list->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($rowlist = $list->fetch_assoc()) {
        $SpielerId = $rowlist["SpielerId"];
//        $sql2 = "SELECT Vorname, Nachname, Bild FROM Spieler WHERE Id IN ($SpielerId)";
//        $result = $conn->query($sql2);
        $result = $stmt->execute();
        while ($data = $result->fetch_assoc()) { //Line 63
            echo "<tr><td>" . $rowlist["Id"] . "</td><td>" . $data["Vorname"] . " " . $data["Nachname"] ."</td><td><img style='max-width: 100px; max-heigth: 100px;' src='" . $data["Bild"] . "'></td></tr>";
        }
    }
}
```

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: what is the value of $SpielerId

Comment: try to print_r(result) prior to fetch @Sebastian

Comment: The value of $SpielerId is the id of the current player I want to get data of.

Comment: You can resume your both queries into 1 and avoid the double while with `SELECT h.id, h.spielerId, s.vorname, s.nachname, s.bild FROM 2Herren h JOIN Spieler s ON s.Id = h.spielerId`

Comment: Well, you could have asked me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are adding this and this isnt used for prepared statements.

```
$sql1 = "SELECT Id, SpielerId FROM 2Herren";
$list = $conn->query($sql1);
```

You also have to execute and run fetch the result with this:

```
//Execute prepared statment
$stmt->execute();
//Get result as assoc_array
$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

It should be like this:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT Id, Vorname, Nachname, Bild FROM Spieler WHERE Id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $SpielerId);

//Execute prepared statment
$stmt->execute();
//Get result as assoc_array
$result = $stmt->get_result();
//Loop through every entry
while ($rowlist = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    var_dump($rowlist);
}
```

Also prepared statements aren't any faster. They are just much more secure and minimize the risk of an sql injection

Comment: Well this was part of the code I used before my friend told me about prepared statements. I wanted to keep it in case I can't find a working solution.

Comment: You were never executing the prepared statement. Also the checking if there are any rows isnt much use because if the result is empty the while loop wont run

Answer (score 0):

The `execute` function of a prepared statement will not return the result associated to the query, but instead a boolean, to determine if the query was executed. You need to get the result with `$stmt->get_result()` after calling `$stmt->execute()`